# Message box with yesno buttons and enabled close button

Tags: asp.net

I have Asp.net web site where I created a message box using dialog result class with yes/no/cancel buttons.

I want only yes/no buttons and close button enabled to the top right of the message box without cancel button.

With yes/no message box it displays only yes/no buttons with close button disabled at the top right of the message box.

Could it be possible?

Comment: What do you mean you created a message box using a dialog result class? What libraries did you use to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible and there are many way to do it.
Consider to use a jquery overlay as colorbox

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/